# SQL Server Agent for job failures without activating the Emails

Tags: sql-server, notifications, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I have a scheduled SQL Agent job which runs over the night every day.

I want to set up a email notification for that job but I also have some constraints for that particular server.

Constraints: I can not activate Emails alter from Job properties due to some security issue. and I also can not create @profile_name to use sp_send_dbmail for the same security reason.

What else option I can consider to send notification of that job when any step failed.

Comment: *"I can not activate Emails alter from Job properties due to some security issue."* Then speak to whomever can; what you want/need to set up are Agent Operators, that can be notified on job failure.

Comment: @Larnu Due to security issue as i mentioned, Email notification activation on that server is not allowed. What else option i can use to inform respective user regarding job failure.
I have a log file "Job creates log file"  and Job writes error message on that log file. 
So is there any option from log file I can use to communicate with users regarding job failure. Power Shell or what ever

Comment: Like I said, speak to whomever can. You can't set up email notifications if you don't have permissions to. What you are effectively asking here is "How do I get around the security permissions I have?"

Comment: The person who has permission he is not voting to do that due to some reason so I am looking for some alternative way. Any idea.

Comment: Get them on board then, or find out what their reasons are; they must have one. At nest, this sounds like "work place politics". If you've been asked to implement something, and someone at the office is intentionally blocking that, it's up to you, them, and the company to come to a solution that works for everything. That person is telling you "no" for some reason, talk to them.